# DevExpress GridView MVC - Set data not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I'm currently testing the possibilities of the DevExpress GridView component. I've created a custom data mapping but it seems that the e.IsSetData event is not fired after a row/cell has been changed.

The returned object is always like

DataRowModel {ID ="SomeValue", Properties=NULL};

I would really appreciate your help.

Please find the grid logic and the model object below.

Thanks in advance.
Constantin

```
settings.CustomUnboundColumnData += (s, e) =>
        {
            var dynamicProperties = Model.DataRowModels[e.ListSourceRowIndex].Properties;

            if (dynamicProperties != null)
            {
                var propertyIdString = e.Column.FieldName;
                var currentValueColumn = dynamicProperties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PropertyId.ToString().Equals(propertyIdString));

                if (currentValueColumn != null)
                {

                    if (e.IsGetData)
                    {
                        if (currentValueColumn == null)
                        {
                            return; 
                        }

                        switch (currentValueColumn.RenderType)
                        {
                            case RenderType.String:
                                e.Value = currentValueColumn.StringValue;
                                break;
                            case RenderType.Integer:
                                e.Value = currentValueColumn.IntValue;
                                break;
                            case RenderType.Boolean:
                                e.Value = currentValueColumn.BooleanValue;
                                break;
                            case RenderType.DateTime:
                                e.Value = currentValueColumn.DateTimeValue;
                                break;
                            default:
                                e.Value = currentValueColumn.StringValue;
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (e.IsSetData && e.Value != null)
                    {
                        currentValueColumn.StringValue = e.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        };


  public class DataRowModel
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }                     -----> The correct value
    public List<DataProperty> Properties { get; set; }  ------> This is always null
}
```

Comment: Assumed `e.ListSourceRowIndex` has integer value, is that `Model.Documents[e.ListSourceRowIndex].Properties` contains null at all times? How you're assigning `List<DataProperty>` from controller side?

Comment: Hi yes - this is correct. I'm returning a Model - Object containing a List of DataRowModel to the View.
There are No Null Values in the list -> Actually it Event is called - but never with e.IsSetData = true - after updating the grid

Comment: As far as I know `CustomUnboundData` event is not generated with `IsSetData` set to true. Possibly what you should do is retrieving data from selected IDs and rebind (this is similar to `RowInsert` or `RowUpdate` methods in webforms, in MVC you need callback to pass values into controller action).

Comment: hm.. ok - can you give me more information about how I should do this?

But I guess there should be a method to get data from the grid back to the controller in case of CustomUnboundData and nested objects... 
I hope it's not that kind of a special thing nobody ever asked for...